# Find circular symlinks with boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, symlink, boost-filesystem

My program is recursively traversing a project directory, where circular symlinks may occur which raise an exception (*too many levels of symbolic links*) in another step of the algorithm. I'd like to find circular symlinks to avoid such exceptions. (Fixing the project by removing circular symlinks is not an option unfortunately.)

Is there a way to uncover circular symlinks using `boost::filesystem`? I have already thought of resolving symlinks with `read_symlink()` and continue it in a recursive way if a symlink resolves to another symlink but that's not exactly the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`boost::filesystem::canonical`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical) or [`weakly_canonical`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#weakly_canonical) (in case the file need not exist).

Note that there can be performance overhead with many symlinks with many path elements, because path elements are `stat`-ed, building a new path instance.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d02b2233b822155)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    using namespace boost::filesystem;
    for (path link : std::vector(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        auto target = canonical(link, ec);
        if (ec) {
            std::cerr << link << " -> " << ec.message() << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << link << " -> " << target << "\n";
        }

        if (ec) {
            target = weakly_canonical(link, ec);
            if (!ec) {
                std::cerr << " -- weakly: -> " << target << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When creating a few symlinks of various quality:

```
ln -sf main.cpp a
ln -sf b b
ln -sf d c
```

Incoking it with `a b c d`:

```
"a" -> "/tmp/1613746951-1110913523/main.cpp"
"b" -> Too many levels of symbolic links
"c" -> No such file or directory
 -- weakly: -> "c"
"d" -> No such file or directory
 -- weakly: -> "d"
```

Comment: Added demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6fb4e4fadb7eddd)**